# How I can save the contents of echo(with html tags) in a variable?

Tags: php

How can I save the contents of echo inside a variable?
I have a php file and a js file with a function. I need to apply this function to a list containing what I have inside echo. So to do that I suppose I have to save the contents of echo inside a variable, and then add the variable to the list.
My problem is that inside echo I am using html tag, so I can't define the variable first and then call echo on it.
How can I do? This is the php file:

```
     <?php

    session_start();
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
      <head>
    <title>NomeSito</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- my CSS -->
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body>


  <?php
            $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','DBsito');
            if (!$db)
            {
              die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
  
            $db_select = mysqli_select_db($db, 'DBsito');
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  
            $categorie = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE BINARY categoria.user_utente = BINARY '$username'");
  ?>
<div class="row">
          <ul id="list">
          
          
          
          <?php   
           
            /* fetch associative array */
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categorie)) {


              echo '
              <li class="list-item"><a href="categoria.php?categoria='.urlencode($row["nome_categoria"]).'">
              <img class="card-icone" shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 src="img/upload/'. $row["icona"] . '" &nbsp;  >
              </a>
              </li>
              ';
                
              }
              
              ?>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js">
              
              </script> 

          </ul>
          </div>

      <?php
      //SET SESSION VARIABLES
      $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
      ?>
                              
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
const phpEcho = '<li class="list-item"><a href="categoria.php?categoria=<?=urlencode($row["nome_categoria"])?>" ><img class="card-icone" shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 src="img/upload/<?=$row["icona"] ?>" &nbsp; ></a></li>';
```

Then you call code inside function like:

```
document.getElementById("myList").innerHTML = phpEcho;
```

you have to replace myList with the Id of your list

Comment: where should i put the second code? at the beginning of the js file?

Comment: If you want to load the phpEcho var when you execute the js function, you need to put the code inside function. If you want to execute code at the loading you need to put the code at the beginning of the js file